# Fedora 18 - Start sshd on boot

Tags: fedora, sshd, chkconfig

I've just installed Fedora 18, and trying to configure `sshd` - I used `chkconfig` but this is only starting `sshd` when a user is logged in. How do I change so that `sshd` starts on system boot?

Comment: @Christopher yes, thanks. Want to add this as answer?

Comment: `chkconfig` _should_ be forwarded to systemctl and just work. What do you mean by "only starting when a user is logged in"?

Comment: @mattdm I mean that I was not able to ssh in to the machine until the user had logged in. I thought it was to do with run level, however I'm a noob and could be mistaken

Comment: @David That's very strange.... Oh! Was the network user controlled? It's possible that the net was only up when someone was logged in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the Fedora 17 method...

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

This will enable sshd so it starts on the next boot and every subsequent boot, but it won't immediately start up sshd.

At this point you can either reboot (which will start it up) or start it manually using

```
systemctl start sshd.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Fedora 21,  I finally zeroed out the Listening Address,`ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` and now when they system reboots I am able to SSH without logging into the system first.